# nodejs/moment - timezone different between dev/server

Tags: node.js, momentjs

We are currently having some issues making momentjs convert to time zones. When on a local Windows computer set to EST, everything works as expected.  When switching to the Ubuntu test server, the date is offset by the utcOffset hours.  Changing the timezone on the Ubuntu box had no visible effect.

We are calling

```
router.get("/report/date", (req, res) => {
    var delayInfo = {
        sendDate: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
        sendTime: moment().format("HH:mm"),
        repeatDuration: 0,
        repeatType: 0,
        sendTimeZone: "Canada/Eastern"
    };

    var _sendDate = null;
    if (delayInfo.sendDate !== null) {
        _sendDate = moment.tz(delayInfo.sendDate + " " + delayInfo.sendTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm", delayInfo.sendTimeZone);
    }
    res.status(200).send(_sendDate);
});
```

On the development machine, we get the expected:

```
"2017-05-05T20:24:00.000Z"
```

On the Ubuntu/Linux machine, we get

```
"2017-05-06T00:25:00.000Z"
```

Node: 7.9.0
Moment: 2.17.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like it is converting the time into the ISO-8601 and thinking that the time is in UTC. I was able to get around this by calling .format().

```
sendDate = moment.tz(delayInfo.sendDate + " " + delayInfo.sendTime, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm", delayInfo.sendTimeZone).format("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:sssZ");
```

which output the date including the offset:

```
'2017-05-05T10:49:000-04:00'
```

Comment: This still gives me the same issue.  On my dev machine `2017-05-05T05:11:000-04:00` on the server `2017-05-05T09:12:000-04:00`

Comment: when setting sendDate and sentTime try: moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD") and moment.utc().format("HH:mm")

Comment: Forcing them all into UTC then using that as the base appears to give me the same across both machines.  thanks Aaron